# Not too sure what I am missing within this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I've been working on getting [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) to work with this CSS/Jquery map and I am almost there, but for some reason I am not sure why I keep getting errors within my javascript.
I know I am missing something, but I'm not sure what and I think I need a fresh set of eyes on it.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ($) {
    $("#map-usa").cssMap({
        size: 960,
        'onClick': function (e) {
            Shadowbox.init({
                players: ["iframe,html"]
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've been running it through JS lint and I'm not sure where the error is stemming from.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your mix of `{}` and `()` is horribly messed up, and you never call your anonymous function.

Comment: You have 4 `{` but only 3 `}`. Syntax error.

Comment: Yep, I finally figured it out. I needed to add a }, but not a });

Comment: @Quentin - I'm not sure what you mean by calling the anonymous function?

Comment: Oh. Never mind, it does get called (`$()` is stupidly overloaded). Of course, it masks `$` with an `undefined` value…

Comment: @Quentin - Ok, thanks. Yeah, I'm trying to follow the documentation with this CSS map and it seems that it should "work" but for some reason Shadowbox is not being triggered when rel attribute is applied to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a the closing brace of the `onClick` function - the reason why your indentation of the last two `});` was not matching:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#map-usa").cssMap({
        size: 960,
        'onClick': function(e) {
            Shadowbox.init({
                players: ["iframe,html"]
            });
        } // <--
    });
});
```